# Including email in restful URIs

Tags: rest, restful-url

In my application I have URIs that include the userid to identify user private resources. And userids are emails, for example:

```
/users/user2@example.com/private-resource
```

It's a good practice to put email in the URI, including characters like `.` and `@`? 
Or should I use some other type of userid? Like an hash for example?

Comment: I think that the choice is really yours I'd personally use a more secure method of identifying your users perhaps MD5 the email when the user is created and then use that as a unique identifiaction

Answer (score 4):

If the email can function as [fixed identifier](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html) it would be ok.

The thing is that most of the time applications will allow users to *change* emails; in this case it would be more bullet proof to control the ID-space yourself, e.g. by using a [surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key). (Because the email (if users can change them) is not the *identity* but merely a property of the resource).

Another argument against emails is - as @Rob points out - a potential security issue.

Comment: Ok, you're right, an email might not be immutable, furthermore it's sensible data, and a surrogate key is the best option. If I implement surrogate keys, how can I let an user access his profile (i.e. GET request on `/users/{userid}`) if he doesn't know his surrogate key? RESTful stateless semantic requires to avoid URIs like `/users/myprofile`..

Comment: @user1781028, you could let users type in `/users/{email}` and then return an [HTTP 302](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) with `/users/{id}` as location; or 404 if the user does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with that... just make sure you URL-encode the appropriate characters.

(Email's kind of sensitive information, though, you might want to pass a hash or surrogate key instead just to protect your users' email addresses if the URLs get passed around.)

Answer (score 0):

though having '-' in uri is absolutely fine.
use of '@' , '#' are discouraged

however, as long as email id is an id e.g. http://example.org/user/mail/{email}/1234
guess thats fine.

Comment: Sorry, but from http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/uri-spec.html I get that `@` is considered a *safe* character - along with `$ | - | _ | @ | . | & | + | -`.